# Can we implement Transaction Management with Mule Community Edition?

Tags: mule

How can we achieve transaction Management with Mule Community Edition 3.7?  Mule has got a Transaction scope but [it's an Enterprise feature link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/transaction-management).

For XA Mule suggests implementing  Bitronix as a Transaction Manager, even though [this is an enterprise feature](http://stage.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Bitronix+to+Manage+Transactions).

Can anyone suggest how I can implement similar Transaction Management with Mule Community Edition 3.7?  Or is it not possible at all?

I would really appreciate if someone can throw some light on this matterd as I need to decide whether we can use Mule ESB Community Edition for our integration Project requirements.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are more likely to get helpful answers if your question is easy to read.  Breaking it into paragraphs and formatting hyperlinks really helps with readability/

Comment: @RanjeetNair, did you get a solution to transaction in Mule CE 3.7?

Answer (score 1):

All transaction management features(including XA) are available in community edition too.

Are you running Mule in embedded mode? If yes, you can use application server's transaction manager. Mule provides wrappers for all major application server (Weblogic,Websphere,JBoss etc)transaction managers.

If running in standalone mode, you can add a custom transaction manager. This custom transaction manager can very well be the same bitronix transaction manager which Mule provides as a enterprise feature. Bitronix is open source and nobody is stopping you to write a wrapper and plugin that to mule as a custom transaction manager.

I have done some experimenting and bitronix is the only transaction manager which I could configure without much effort.

Comment: On Mule 3.5, JDBC was deprecated. The substitute new Database Component in my tests does not works with XA in Mule CE. What should be the way to use XA in Mule CE 3.7 now?